# PyInstaller + Ui Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qt-designer

I'm trying to build a one-file EXE with PyInstaller.
I'm importing it with `Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("first_qt.ui")` code inside **main.py** file.

```
pyinstaller --name="MyApplication"  --onefile main.py
```

Code output:

```
24 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
24 INFO: Python: 3.7.5
24 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.0.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
25 INFO: wrote /home/you/Installer/MyApplication.spec
27 INFO: UPX is not available.
28 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/you/Installer', '/home/you/Installer']
28 INFO: checking Analysis
28 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
28 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
30 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
31 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1719 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
1741 INFO: Caching module hooks...
1744 INFO: Analyzing /home/you/Installer/main.py
1831 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
2483 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v3
2486 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt5.uic.port_v2
2577 INFO: Loading module hooks...
2577 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
2617 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
2694 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
2737 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.uic.py"...
2738 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
2739 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
2759 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
2771 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
2771 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
2772 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
2818 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
2831 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
2831 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
2834 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
2836 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_certifi.py'
2843 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
5002 INFO: Looking for eggs
5002 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
5058 INFO: Using Python library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
5062 INFO: Warnings written to /home/you/Installer/build/MyApplication/warn-MyApplication.txt
5095 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /home/you/Installer/build/MyApplication/xref-MyApplication.html
5105 INFO: checking PYZ
5105 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
5105 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/you/Installer/build/MyApplication/PYZ-00.pyz
5406 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/you/Installer/build/MyApplication/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
5411 INFO: checking PKG
5412 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
5412 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
28572 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
28576 INFO: Bootloader /home/you/.local/share/virtualenvs/Installer-p1t8sryV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run
28577 INFO: checking EXE
28577 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
28577 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
28577 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /home/you/Installer/dist/MyApplication
28979 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

```
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "site-packages/PyQt5/uic/__init__.py", line 200, in loadUiType
  File "site-packages/PyQt5/uic/Compiler/compiler.py", line 111, in compileUi
  File "site-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 1020, in parse
  File "xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
  File "xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'first_qt.ui'
[23863] Failed to execute script main
```

I tried to convert it to first.py file with pyuic5 and try failed.
Is there another way?

Similar topics: [PyInstaller + UI Files - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888581/pyinstaller-ui-files-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

**Edit:**

After executing the `pyuic5 first_qt.ui > output.py` command, I added import output to `main.py`:

```
...
import output

#Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("first_qt.ui")

# Import .ui forms for the GUI using function resource_path()
form = resource_path("first_qt.ui")
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(form)

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
...
```

I got an error output like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
NameError: name 'resource_path' is not defined
[7217] Failed to execute script main
```

I got rid of the above error. Now I've encountered an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "site-packages/PyQt5/uic/__init__.py", line 200, in loadUiType
  File "site-packages/PyQt5/uic/Compiler/compiler.py", line 111, in compileUi
  File "site-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 1020, in parse
  File "xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
  File "xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEID22LkJ/first_qt.ui'
[9606] Failed to execute script main
```

**Edit2:**
MyApplication.spec output:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/home/Installer'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[("/home/Installer/first_qt.ui", ".")],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='MyApplication',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Then I ran the `pyinstaller MyApplication.spec` command.

Problem solved.

Comment: Have you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37920111/6622587? if you have done it then show it even if it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, I tried and I got the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
NameError: name 'resource_path' is not defined
[3050] Failed to execute script main`

Comment: Place the **detailed information** of your attempt and show it as an edition of your question. That is, point out step by step your attempt to understand where it is failing (you may not have applied the solution correctly)

Comment: Have you added the resource_path method code in your .py? ```# Define function to import external files when using PyInstaller.
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)```

Comment: After executing the `pyuic5 first_qt.ui > output.py`command, I added `import output`to `main.py`

Comment: Do not put it in the comments section, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Okey. Thank you.

Comment: move `def resource_path(relative_path): ....` before `form = resource_path("first_qt.ui")`

Comment: `pyuic5 first_qt.ui > output.py` is unnecesary, show your .spec

Comment: change `datas=["/home/you/Installer/first_qt.ui"],` and execute: `pyinstaller MyApplication.spec`

Comment: Oopss: change to `datas=[("/home/you/Installer/first_qt.ui", ".")]`

Comment: For everything Thank you so much @eyllanesc . You solved the problem. You’re awesome!