# Errors in Converting .py that load with ui file into exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I want to convert my .py that load with the UI file into exe.

I had followed the steps from [PyInstaller + Ui Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719083/pyinstaller-ui-files) and [PyInstaller + UI Files - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888581/pyinstaller-ui-files-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

I added the resource_path method code in my .py

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
form = resource_path("qt_designer.ui")
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(form)
```

I had also made changes to my MyApplication.spec as such:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Alvin\\PycharmProjects\\untitled'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\Alvin\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\qt_designer.ui',".")],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='MyApplication',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

But I am getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 380, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 227, in loadUi
  File "site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 72, in loadUi
  File "site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1013, in parse
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 586, in parse
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'qt_designer.ui'
[761476] Failed to execute script main
```

Screenshot of the error

[image]

Can anyone help me to point out my mistake or steps that I followed wrongly?

Comment: When do you get that error?

Comment: I get that error after starting myapplication.exe

Comment: How do you compile the .py?

Comment: I use pyinstaller --name="MyApplication"  --onefile main.py follow by 
pyinstaller MyApplication.spec

Comment: mmm, just run `pyinstaller MyApplication.spec`(Check that with your previous commands you have not modified the .spec)

Comment: I assume you mean i dont change datas in the spec file. After running that command, I get this error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Alvin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI8343282\\qt_designer.ui

Comment: Yes, since executing `pyinstaller --name="MyApplication" --onefile main.py` rewrites the .spec

Comment: Am I suppose to put the qt_designer.ui into the MEI8343282 file?