# How do I make .exe files using Pyinstaller that also imports .ui files?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pyinstaller, executable

I am trying to make an executable (.exe) file of a PyQt5 GUI. The code runs without any problem in PyCharm. The code imports a .ui file  and another .py file. It basically has the same format as below.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QListWidgetItem
import PyQt5.uic as uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import numpy as np

loaded_ui = uic.loadUiType("tester_layout.ui")[0]
class MainGUIobject(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, loaded_ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None): # Initialization of the code
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        super(MainGUIobject, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.randomFunction)
        
    def randomFunction(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(str("Hello world!"))
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainGUIobject()
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
    widget.setFixedWidth(500)
    widget.setFixedHeight(300)
    widget.setWindowTitle("pyinstaller_tester")
    widget.show()
    # sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, when I use Pyinstaller to pack them, the generated .exe file opens up and just closes without opening the GUI. When I tried to run this on the terminal I get an error message saying

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                        File "tester.py", line 36, in                                                                   File "PyQt5\uic_*init*_.py", line 198, in loadUiType                                                   File "PyQt5\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 110, in compileUi                                           File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1013, in parse                                                       File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse                                                    File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 584, in parse                                                   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tester_layout.ui'                              [17800] Failed to execute script 'tester' due to unhandled exception!

I did some research and found this page([PyInstaller + UI Files - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888581/pyinstaller-ui-files-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory/37920111#37920111)) which seems like a good solution but I am having a hard time implementing it to my own code. I wasn't sure how to use the resource_path function. So, far this is what I tried, and doesn't work even in PyCharm (The current error that I get is "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'").

Is there a way to fix this problem

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QListWidgetItem
import PyQt5.uic as uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import numpy as np

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


UI = resource_path("python_image_inspector_layout.ui")[0]
loaded_ui = uic.loadUiType(UI)

class MainGUIobject(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, loaded_ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None): # Initialization of the code
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        super(MainGUIobject, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.randomFunction)
        
    def randomFunction(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(str("Hello world!"))
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainGUIobject()
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
    widget.setFixedWidth(500)
    widget.setFixedHeight(300)
    widget.setWindowTitle("pyinstaller_tester")
    widget.show()
    # sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm pretty new to PyQt5 and making GUIs. I would love any kind of help.

Comment: Not only do you have to use `sys._MEIPASS` but you also have to use `add-data`

Comment: Could you give me more specifics on how to do that? I am just not sure what I need to change or add to my code