# Create executable file for distribution with multiple dependencies

Tags: pyqt5, exe, qt-designer

I really need some guidance here:
I created an app using pyQT5. In my project folder theres now an main.py file which runs the app when executed. There are also other .py files which are needed and imported.
Also there lies a .ui file, extracted from QTDesigner which I import via uic.loadUi("myGUI.ui").
Of course in each .py file I imported some libraries which I installed into my virtual environment such as pyQT5, numpy and such.

I now want to merge all this into a single executable file, which my colleagues can run without having to install python or any libraries.

I know this is a pretty common problem but I didnt find anything related.

Thanks for your time and help!

I've read that I have to convert my .ui file to an .py file but since i imported the .ui file as uic.loadUI("..") i figured this conversion will crash my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyInstaller + UI Files - FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888581/pyinstaller-ui-files-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using a tag on your question. The `distribution` tag does not mean what you think.

Comment: Note that if you are asking "what can I use to distribute my python program as a standalone executable", then your question is off topic, as asking for recommendations about software/modules/libraries (or generic tutorials) is not in the scope of StackOverflow.